# Github Action failed with ruby mismatch

Tags: ruby, github, github-actions, workflow

I am facing an issue in which workflow file is failing again and again. I am adding issue image and workflow file .

```
pod_lint:
    @bundle exec pod spec lint project.podspec  \
    --sources='/repopath/podspecs.git,https://github.com/{dependency}.git,https://cdn.cocoapods.org/' \
    --private \
    --fail-fast \
    --no-clean
```

Pod_lint.yaml

```
on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/heads
    branches:
      - master        # Push events on master branch

name: Podspec Lint
jobs:
  test:
    name: Podspec Lint
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ruby: [2.0.0, 2.7]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          ruby-version: ${{ matrix.ruby }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
      - name: Podspec Lint
        run: |
          gem install cocoapods-keys
          bundle install
          bundle exec pod install
          bundle exec rake
          make pod_lint
```

issue:
[image]

I have check lot of about it. any clue?

Comment: Forgot to replace the second `actions/checkout` with [`ruby/setup-ruby@v1`](https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby)? :)

Comment: See https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby#matrix-of-ruby-versions.